# Debounce onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, debouncing

I have a Material UI Textfield that contains an `onChange`.
This `onChange`, takes the `event` and execute the function `handleOnChange`. With this current implementation, the function `handleOnChange` is executed every-time the `event` changes.

It it possible to use `debounce` to execute the function only after 2000ms directly on the `event`?

**My textfield**

```
<TextField
  onChange={
    event =>
      handleOnChange(
      event.target.value,
      firstValue,
      secondValue,                            
    )
/>
```

**My function**

```
const handleOnChange = (value, firstValue, secondValue) => {
  ...do something..
}
```

**I tried** the following, but `handleOnChange` still fires at every `event` change, not after 2000ms.

```
<TextField
  onChange={
    event =>
      _.debounce(handleOnChange(
      event.target.value,
      firstValue,
      secondValue,                            
    ), 2000)
/>
```

Comment: You could store the handleOnChange args in a singe state hook and debounce the state change, then whenever the debounced state changes, run a useEffect that calls handleOnChange with the debounces state value.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide a code example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a debounced instance on every event call. Try creating one instance of debounced function and use it in your handler. Something like this:

```
const handleOnChange = _.debounce(change => {
  console.log(change);
}, 1000);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={event => handleOnChange(event.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are passing the **result** of the handleOnChange() function to debounce, rather than a reference to the function.

Try something more like this:

```
<TextField
  onChange={
    event =>
      _.debounce(() => handleOnChange(
          event.target.value,
          firstValue,
          secondValue,                            
        ), 2000)
/>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but my `handleOnChange` does not fire at all

Comment: Apologies, I will have to have a bit more of a think about the structure of that call... perhaps it is meant to be more like `onChange=_.debounce(event => handleOnChange(...), 2000)`. If this doesn't work, I suggest posting a more complete example.